# MySQL stored procedure called in NodeJS, but in Result number field values are not Rounded properly (Workig properly in Workbench and MySQL console)

Tags: mysql, node.js

MySQL stored procedure called in NodeJS, but in Result number field values are not Rounded properly (Working properly in Workbench and MySQL console).
Example : sale column value (1.8199999999999998) is ROUND for 2 Decimals
Output In WorkBench and MySQL console is **1.81** for sale column.
But in NodeJs Procedure Result Output is 1.8199999999999998 for sale column.

I have used "mysql2/promise"  library in NodeJS.

Comment: Please attach your code as well, it will help bit more to solve your problem.